# How to read values from two csv and do operation on b/w its column in spark java api?

Tags: java, hadoop, spark-java, bigdata

I have two Csv in hadoop,say csv1,csv2. Both csvs contain two columns (timestamp and somevalue),say for csv1 columns are t1,v1 and for csv2 columns are t2,v2.
I want to calculate v1*v2 for every t1 = t2 (for same timestamp) and store the result as text file in hdfs using spark java Api.

I am new to spark, plz someone help me.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can do it in scala , maybe you can get the gist of what I am doing and implement it yourself:

```
scala> val df1=sc.parallelize(Seq((1001,2),(1002,3),(1003,4))).toDF("t1","v1")
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [t1: int, v1: int]


scala> val df2=sc.parallelize(Seq((1001,3),(1002,4),(1005,4))).toDF("t2","v2")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [t2: int, v2: int]

scala> df1.join(df2,df1("t1")===df2("t2"))
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [t1: int, v1: int ... 2 more fields]

scala> res1.show
+----+---+----+---+                                                             
|  t1| v1|  t2| v2|
+----+---+----+---+
|1002|  3|1002|  4|
|1001|  2|1001|  3|
+----+---+----+---+

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> val result=res1.withColumn("foo",res1("v1") * res1("v2"))
result: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [t1: int, v1: int ... 3 more fields]

scala> result.show
+----+---+----+---+---+                                                         
|  t1| v1|  t2| v2|foo|
+----+---+----+---+---+
|1002|  3|1002|  4| 12|
|1001|  2|1001|  3|  6|
+----+---+----+---+---+
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanx for solution, I tried with these concept but not getting exact solution.The timestamp column contains values like 2016-09-01 15:31:58+00:00. And I want to load csv and split it into columns and result should be like (t1,v*v2).

Comment: Then use convert it into spark timestamp first and then do these steps, or if you want to do it in a easy way, just use string instead.